# UNIX (AIX) Version of IFS <<< command

Tags: variables, unix, ifs

I've got a script working on Linux perfectly, but when trying to get this running on a UNIX box, there is one command I cannot seem to convert for the life of me, its...

```
 IFS=\| read TableName DataBase Schema MD5Check<<< "$NextFile"
```

$NextFile is a variable created in a line of code before which will contain 4 columns, separated by a |

Its the <<< which isn't liked, but I just cannot find the alternative to reading from a variable in UNIX. Any help?

Comment: `echo "$NextFile" | IFS=\| read ...` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The portable way to do this is:

```
IFS=\| read TableName DataBase Schema MD5Check<<EOF
$NextFile
EOF
```

But if you can restrict the scope of the variables (you can, but you may need to refactor):

```
echo "$NextFile" | { IFS=\| read TableName DataBase Schema MD5Check
# Inside the braces, the variables are defined
}
```